# Terminal start-up stuck after upgrading to Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: macos, bash, mac, terminal, macos-catalina

I just upgraded my Mac operating system to 10.15.1 (Catalina), and I'm now unable to interact with my terminal properly. When I open the Terminal application (or iTerm), it outputs the last attempted login time but does not then give me a prompt to enter commands.

I can see via Activity Monitor that the Terminal application is running a number of bash processes in the background that are possibly throwing errors, however I'm not sure how to decipher them. Here's a sample of what one such process is writing to `/dev/stdout`:

```
Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __fork  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        1314
        read  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        909
        stat$INODE64  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        50
        szone_force_unlock  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        35
        __ioctl  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        34
        tiny_malloc_from_free_list  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        33
        _objc_atfork_parent  (in libobjc.A.dylib)        23
        tiny_free_list_add_ptr  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        23
        _sigtramp  (in libsystem_platform.dylib)        22
        __open  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        15
        _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell  (in libsystem_platform.dylib)        12
        _malloc_fork_parent  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        9
        sigprocmask  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        9
        __pipe  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        7
        __wait4  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        7
        mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        7
        ???  (in bash)  load address 0x10cac2000 + 0x28ae1  [0x10caeaae1]        6
        close  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        6
        tiny_free_no_lock  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        6
        tiny_malloc_should_clear  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)        6
        fork  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        5
        setpgid  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        5

Binary Images:
       0x10cac2000 -        0x10cb42ff7 +bash (118.40.2) <30A60B27-69AE-323A-AA7E-B8B648C54096> /bin/bash
       0x10d8e2000 -        0x10d972b5f  dyld (733.6) <DAFEA246-2F9A-3DCB-A37C-4246D4F92770> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff61168000 -     0x7fff61169ff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1281) <1DD1BCD2-2C85-3B81-8CAF-224FB042F441> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff61446000 -     0x7fff61499fff  libc++.1.dylib (800.7) <1D42387D-206A-3F06-9B5F-705B83EAC295> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff6149a000 -     0x7fff614aefff  libc++abi.dylib (800.7) <D89ABFBF-3754-35AB-BAEE-FBF14857F79B> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff62939000 -     0x7fff62968ff7  libncurses.5.4.dylib (57) <7115BD9E-9A53-3538-BA7C-6D71E8C0F9F1> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
...
```

This problem is occurring when I have my Terminal preferences set to open shell with "Default login shell", which worked fine on my previous OS version, and with the startup command `/bin/bash`. Interestingly, I'm able to start up my terminal successfully when I change the shell startup command to `/bin/sh`, however I'm then unable to source my `bash_profile` in sessions started that way (when I type `source ~/.bash_profile`, the process hangs).

I tried renaming the file `com.apple.Terminal.plist` to `com.apple.Terminal.OLD.plist`, as per the suggestion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299651/terminal-on-mac-wont-launch-a-shell-stuck-on-login-incorrect) (that wasn't exactly my problem, but I was desperate, and it didn't work in any case).

I'm stuck—help much appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what's in your .bash_profile. My first recommendation would be to try run with /bin/sh, then run `set -x; source ~/.bash_profile`. This will make it print the commands (or their equivalent) as it executes them, so you can get some idea where it's getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that with Catalina, Apple has [replaced](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88278/change-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh/88296#88296) bash with zsh as the default shell. (Great job letting everyone know)

Consequently, my shell scripts were hanging on the command `builtin cd //..`, because `cd` isn't a valid command in zsh. I ended up switching my shell from bash to zsh and porting over my `.bash_profile` settings to `.zshrc`. Thanks Apple, I'm really glad I spent the past 2.5 days of my life on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using iTerm (iTerm2), go to "Preferences > Profiles > Shell" and change the startup command to /bin/bash (as of OsX 10.15.4), and start a shell.